# Objective-C. NSString is changed to NSCFNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nscfnumber

I have some code in Objective-C. I think, I received type NSString, but when I try to save it in Core Data, I get a `user.clientID = clientID;` error, like:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "clientID"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSCFNumber; value = 29.'
```

So, here's my code:

my Data manager singleton **PKDataManager.h**

```
+(PKDataManager*) sharedManager;

- (void)updateCoreDataUserWithID:(NSString*) userID
                 andClientID:(NSString*) clientID;
```

**PKDataManager.m**

```
- (void)updateCoreDataUserWithID:(NSString*) userID
                 andClientID:(NSString*) clientID{

       PKUser*user = [NSEntityDescription 
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PKUser" 
       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
       user.userID = userID;
       user.clientID = clientID; ///// error showing here
       [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:user];
       [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

my singleton for API **PKServerManager.h**

```
+ (PKServerManager*) sharedManager;

- (void) sendUserID:(NSString*) userID
              onSuccess:(void(^)(NSString* clientID)) success
              onFailure:(void(^)(NSError* error, NSInteger statusCode)) failure;
```

**PKServerManager.m**

```
- (void) sendUserID:(NSString*) userID
                  onSuccess:(void(^)(NSString* clientID)) success
                  onFailure:(void(^)(NSError* error, NSInteger statusCode)) failure{
        NSDictionary* params =
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         userID, @"userID", nil];
        [self.requestOperationManager
         POST:@"app/registration"
         parameters:params
         progress:nil
         success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSDictionary* responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
            NSString* clientID = (NSString*)[responseObject objectForKey:@"clientId"];
            if (success) {
                success(clientID);
            }
         } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
         }];
}
```

and my CODE:
**PKProfile.m**

```
[[PKServerManager sharedManager]
     sendUserID:profile.userID
     onSuccess:^(NSString* clientID) {
         NSLog(@"clientID %@", clientID);
         [[PKDataManager sharedManager] updateCoreDataUserWithID: profile.userID
                                                     andClientID: clientID];
     }
     onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
     }];
```

Comment: Where is `profile.userID` set?

Comment: Put a breakpoint after `NSString* clientID = (NSString*)[responseObject objectForKey:@"clientId"];`check on debugger if clientID is actually a NSString or you are just forcing a cast on a NSNumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is telling you that the response included a numeric value for client ID (and is represented in the `responseObject` as a `NSNumber`; `NSCFNumber` is part of the broader `NSNumber` class cluster). It would appear that your JSON response included something like:

```
{
    ...,
    "clientId": 42
}
```

rather than

```
{
    ...,
    "clientId": "42"
}
```

Rather than focusing on how to convert this `NSNumber` to a `NSString`, I would instead be inclined to consider changing client ID throughout the app to be a `NSInteger` (or a `NSNumber`). If these IDs are really numeric values, it's best to have a type that reflects that.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! If `clientId` is number (integer) value, then it should be handled using `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 3):

in your **PKServerManager.m**

replace following line of code:

```
NSString* clientID = (NSString*)[responseObject objectForKey:@"clientId"];
```

with

```
NSString* clientID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"clientId"]];
```

Comment: Which makes you want to ask why this code assumes `clientId` is a string but the server is sending it as a number.